# Line break in date axis with amcharts

Tags: line, break, amcharts

As you can see here http://allopensensors.com/profile/andreas/
the date on x-axis is nonreadable. I'd like to add a line break. How can i solve this?

```
 AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.pathToImages = "http://allopensensors.com/amcharts/images/";
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.marginLeft = 10;
            chart.categoryField = "year";
            chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS";

            // listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is inited) and call zoomChart method when it happens
            chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

            // AXES
            // category
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
           // categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
             categoryAxis.minPeriod = "200"; // our data is yearly, so we set minPeriod to YYYY
            categoryAxis.dashLength = 3;
            categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
            categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;

            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.inside = true;
            valueAxis.dashLength = 3;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPH
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.type = "smoothedLine"; // this line makes the graph smoothed line.
            graph.lineColor = "#d1655d";
            graph.negativeLineColor = "#637bb6"; // this line makes the graph to change color when it drops below 0
            graph.bullet = "round";
            graph.bulletSize = 8;
            graph.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
            graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
            graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
            graph.lineThickness = 2;
            graph.valueField = "value";
            graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>";
            chart.addGraph(graph);



            // CURSOR
            var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
            chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
            chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
            chartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS";
            chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

            // SCROLLBAR
            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

            chart.creditsPosition = "bottom-right";

            // WRITE
            chart.write("chartdiv");
        });

        // this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
        function zoomChart() {
             // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
          //   chart.zoomToDates(new Date(1972, 0), new Date(2200, 0));
```

chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 40, chartData.length - 1);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it readable, you can rotate the labels with custom angle. Try *categoryAxis.labelRotation : 45*

For Reference: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/

Hope it helps!